# Get rows with a mix of specific values or null if value does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this.

| id | value | text | type | eqPath | enabled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Unknown | NULL | NULL | True |
| 2 | 1 | Production | Production | NULL | True |
| 3 | 2 | Idle | Idle | NULL | True |
| 4 | 3 | Maintenance | Maintenance | NULL | True |
| 5 | 4 | Changeover | Changeover | NULL | True |
| 6 | 5 | Cleaning | Cleaning | NULL | True |
| 7 | 6 | Engineering | Other | NULL | True |
| 8 | 7 | Training | Other | NULL | True |
| 9 | 8 | Pause | Idle | NULL | True |
| 10 | 1 | Running | Production | 'Seattle/Sorting/Line 1' | True |
| 11 | 1 | Running | Production | 'Seattle/Sorting/Line 2' | True |
| 12 | 5 | Washing | Cleaning | 'Seattle/Sorting/Line 2' | False |
| 13 | 10 | Locked Out | Maintenance | 'Seattle/Sorting/Line 2' | False |

When I use this code, I get back all of the rows with an `eqPath` of `NULL`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM modes
WHERE eqPath IS NULL
```

| id | value | text | type | eqPath | enabled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Unknown | NULL | NULL | True |
| 2 | 1 | Production | Production | NULL | True |
| 3 | 2 | Idle | Idle | NULL | True |
| 4 | 3 | Maintenance | Maintenance | NULL | True |
| 5 | 4 | Changeover | Changeover | NULL | True |
| 6 | 5 | Cleaning | Cleaning | NULL | True |
| 7 | 6 | Engineering | Other | NULL | True |
| 8 | 7 | Training | Other | NULL | True |
| 9 | 8 | Pause | Idle | NULL | True |

Now I need one that returns the same table, but if the user requests a specific `eqPath`, then it would also show up in the list, BUT the value column has to be unique with the row containing the `eqPath` to replace the row with the `NULL`
`eqPath`.

| id | value | text | type | eqPath | enabled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Unknown | NULL | NULL | True |
| 11 | 1 | Running | Production | 'Seattle/Sorting/Line 2' | True |
| 3 | 2 | Idle | Idle | NULL | True |
| 4 | 3 | Maintenance | Maintenance | NULL | True |
| 5 | 4 | Changeover | Changeover | NULL | True |
| 12 | 5 | Washing | Cleaning | 'Seattle/Sorting/Line 2' | False |
| 7 | 6 | Engineering | Other | NULL | True |
| 8 | 7 | Training | Other | NULL | True |
| 9 | 8 | Pause | Idle | NULL | True |
| 13 | 10 | Locked Out | Maintenance | 'Seattle/Sorting/Line 2' | False |

This is the code I am trying, but I realize it is wrong.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM modes
WHERE eqPath = ?
OR eqPath IS NULL
GROUP BY value
```

Comment: basically it sounds like you want something like (pseudocode) `where ( (eqPath=@paramname or eqPath is null) or (@paramName is null))` - named param @paramname is user supplied

Comment: @Nikki9696 I did tag it. It's `sql-server` or `MSSQL`. I think those are the same thing. As for your code, when I try that, I get both the row with id 1 and id 10 which are conflicting because they have the same value.

Comment: Please describe in more detail how the row is "replaced". Your current example chose `'Seattle/Sorting/Line 2'` for value `1`, but why not `'Seattle/Sorting/Line 1'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to mark the rows and use it in filter to get the expected result.

A sql query will be something like -

```
select id, value, text, type, eqPath, enabled
from 
   (select * ,  
      row_number() over( partition by value order by eqPath desc) rn 
   from <your-table>
   where (eqPath is null or eqPath = ?) ) tbl 
where rn = 1 
order by value
```

the `row_number` in the query will put a row number for each rows and resets when the value changes, so finally those rows with row number matching 1 will the ones we need to fetch.

**[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68c517186cd986e3e124e047468cda97)** is a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with a solution:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM modes
WHERE eqPath IS NULL
AND value NOT IN (
    SELECT value 
    FROM modes 
    WHERE eqPath = ?
)
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM modes
WHERE eqPath = ?
ORDER BY value
```